# Ansible replace command

Tags: regex, ansible

I want replace `export PS1="$highred[${xx_sid}@\h \W]$normalr$"` with `export PS1="\[$highred\][${xx_sid}@\h \W]\[$normalr\]\$ "` in `/home/oracle/.bash_profile`.

Playbook is running fine without any error but its not doing any changes. Ansible version 2.5.2.

Below is playbook:

```
    ---
     - name : 'vj'
       hosts : 'all'
       gather_facts : 'false'
       tasks :
        - name : 'replace line'
          replace :
            path : '/home/oracle/.bash_profile'
            regexp : "export PS1=\"$highred[${xx_sid}@\\h \\W]$normalr$\""
            replace : "export PS1=\"\\[$highred\\][${xx_sid}@\\h \\W]\\[$normalr\\]\\$ \""
            backup : yes
```

Here is debug mode output:

```
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "after": null,
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": true,
            "before": null,
            "content": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "follow": false,
            "force": null,
            "group": null,
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/home/oracle/.bash_profile",
            "regexp": "export PS1=\"$highred[${xx_sid}@\\h \\W]$normalr$\"",
            "remote_src": null,
            "replace": "export PS1=\"\\[$highred\\][${xx_sid}@\\h \\W]\\[$normalr\\]\\$ \"",
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": ""
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

Appreciate any inputs from experts.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an `ok` status, it means the regular expression specified in `regexp` argument was not found.

And it was not found because regular expression syntax makes use of characters like `$`, `[`, `\`.

To match the string you want, you should specify:

```
regexp: export PS1="\$highred\[\${xx_sid}@\\h \\W\]\$normalr\$"
```

---

BTW, there is no need to quote the whole string. If you do, then it gets more complicated:

```
regexp: "export PS1=\"\\$highred\\[\\${xx_sid}@\\\\h \\\\W\\]\\$normalr\\$\""
```